# Could not create connection to github.com:443

Tags: eww

Trying to `eww https://github.com` on `emacs -q` with the following debug stacktrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not create connection to github.com:443")
  signal(error ("Could not create connection to github.com:443"))
  error("Could not create connection to %s:%d" "github.com" 443)
  url-http([cl-struct-url "https" nil nil "github.com" nil "/" nil nil t nil t] eww-render (nil "https://github.com/" nil #<buffer *eww*>) nil tls)
  url-https([cl-struct-url "https" nil nil "github.com" nil "/" nil nil t nil t] eww-render (nil "https://github.com/" nil #<buffer *eww*>))
  url-retrieve-internal("https://github.com/" eww-render (nil "https://github.com/" nil #<buffer *eww*>) nil nil)
  url-retrieve("https://github.com/" eww-render ("https://github.com/" nil #<buffer *eww*>))
  eww("https://github.com/")
  funcall-interactively(eww "https://github.com/")
  #<subr call-interactively>(eww t nil)
  elmacro-record-command(#<subr call-interactively> eww nil nil)
  apply(elmacro-record-command #<subr call-interactively> (eww nil nil))
  call-interactively(eww nil nil)
  command-execute(eww)
```

Mac OS version 10.11.6, GnuTLS 3.5.18 from Brew.

GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1404.47) of 2018-03-20

`curl` works fine, regular browser works fine, any other website through `eww` works fine.

For some reason, specifically `github.com:443` with `url-http.el` library fails.

To be clear, I'm not trying to browse `github.com` in `eww`. However, tooling that relies on the same library as `eww` breaks in the same way as `eww` - I'm confident if I can figure out I'll fix the other.

Looking for any help on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I've flagged this question because of the down-vote without any comment. Maybe, the moderators can track down the people doing such thing. I also compensate that down-vote now with my up-vote. IMHO the question does not deserve a down-vote. The question is clear and even detailed information about the error, the system, and versions is given.

Comment: My guess is the question is specific to my system. Which is the way to get downvotes on stackexchange sites since it tries to amass questions that apply to as many users as possible. However, I do not know where else it makes sense to post it.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? It might help to run Wireshark and see where the connection fails (in the TLS handshake, or after). A tutorial on Wireshark is more than I can write in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that this version of Emacs(`emacs-mac` from Brew) and the latest version of `gnutls` from Brew are incompatible.

Installing `emacs-plus` solved issue for me.

Comment: dunno if there is a better fix or not, but that worked for me